# php preg_match at sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hello I want to match "@" in the following line,

```
create@create_time:"2012-05-30 21:14:35.0",update_time:"2012-05-31 22:05:46.0"

preg_replace("@", "", $content)

preg_replace("\@", "", $content)
```

Neither of them are working.

Answer (score 6):

For posterity: In case anyone stumbles across this because they are confused by usage of at-signs in regular expressions which are part of somebody else's code, `@` is occasionally used as a starting and ending [regex-delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The below quote also relates to why OP's attempts at matching a literal '@' were unsuccessful (emphasis mine):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is ***required*** that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

In other words, any regular-expression string *must* start and end with a matching character identified by either the character-class `[^A-Za-z\s\\]` or – if you feel like you can deal with any headaches their usage might cause you – a pair of matching grouping characters `<>` `{}` `[]` `()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read error message you've found that your regex lacks of delimiters.

A correct one would be `~@~`

But, you don't need `preg_replace` in this case and you should go with

```
str_replace("@", "", $content)
```

Comment: `~@~` is "a" correct one, not "the". Other correct ones include `/@/`, `(@)`, `#@#`, or even `@\@@`. In fact any character can be the delimiter except letters, numbers, backslashes and whitespaces.

Comment: @Kolink: grammar driven development, GDD ;-)